# Are there new facebook restriction for Rfacebook package?

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I want to get some data from Facebook, so I wanted to create application to get token for 60 days like I did few months ago. Then everything worked well, I just followed steps from the tutorial like this:

http://thinktostart.com/analyzing-facebook-with-r/

So It was enough to create "empty" application, write in R with proper id and secret

```
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="123456789", app_secret="1A2B3C4D",extended_permissions = TRUE)
```

fill website page as `http://localhost:1410/` and autenthication was complete and I was able to make get some data from facebook. It seems that it is not so easy anymore.

When I try to follow exactly the same steps it seems that now I have to fill in my application (with some description, photos...) and "send" it to submission.

Do you have similar problem or I just miss something? I just want to use information from facebook for my own use, not for business or something. Is there any (other) way to get a token for R which allows me to get some information from Facebook without filling application. I don't think that filling it with some fake data will pass facebook verification.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to use information from facebook for my own use

Then you *don’t* need to submit it for review.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#roles – it explains that you can ask any user that has a “role” in the app (meaning admin, developer or tester) for *any* permission without prior review.

For one, this is of course implemented this way, so that people can actually *test* the functionality they are developing properly. And it is also an “official loophole” for apps such as yours, that are for “private use” only, and not meant to be used by the general public in the first place.

(And this has nothing whatsoever with the Rfacebook package – it is the same for all apps, no matter what framework/SDK they might be using.)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

As @CBroe said earlier, you do not need an approved app, you just need to add the users of the app as admin in the app's role menu in Facebook Developers.

Follow these steps and you will get your permanent FB token:

- Create new application at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ with basic setup
- Fill in the app name in lower case and without the words Facebook or FB for display name and namespace, category set to Business
- In "Settings/Basic" I added a new "Website" platform with the URL of `http://localhost:1410/` and `localhost` as the "App Domain"
- In the "Settings/Advanced" tab I added `http://localhost:1410/` as the `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

Then, run this code:

```
library(httr)
app <- oauth_app('facebook', appid, appsecret)
Sys.setenv("HTTR_SERVER_PORT" = "1410/")
tkn <- oauth2.0_token(
oauth_endpoints('facebook'), app, scope = c('ads_management', 'read_insights'), 
type  = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', cache = FALSE)
save(tkn, file = "~/Documents/RFiles/fb_token")  # save the token for future use
```

Make sure you put `'read_insights'` in `scope`, otherwise you are not telling Facebook what kind of permissions you want the app to take.

Finally you can use the token:

```
library(Rfacebook)
load("~/Documents/RFiles/fb_token")
```